# Customised HTML Selection Menus

Tags: jquery, html, css

Without wanting to resort to jQuery, I'd really like to place a dropdown button to my select dropdown.

I have a down icon which works by pushing (hiding) the overflow of the select, and then replacing it with a div with a background-image. It's a bit of a hack, but standard.

**HTML** (Minimal)

```
<div class="styled-select">
  <select>
    <option>Mike</option>
    <option>Jonathan Frank Long</option> ... etc
  </select>
</div>
```

**CSS** (Simplified)

```
.styled-select{
   overflow: hidden;
   background:url(input-box-fade.png) no-repeat right transparent;
   background-position: 100%;
   background-size:200px;
   width:300px;
}
```

My designer has given me an icon with a blurred gradient background too, however when there is a long item (like a long select option), then I've found the icon sits BENEATH the text.

> Is there anyway I can bring this forward to truly overlay the
>   selection?

See the [codepen example](https://codepen.io/moletek/pen/grBRWe). Thanks

Comment: It's a bit hard to say, you are using external minified style sheets in your code pen. When I remove them and change the padding to `padding: 5px 65px 5px 8px;` on the `select` css selctor it seems I get the behaviour you're asking for.: [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LNapWo)

Comment: Hey thanks for this MichaPau, yes sorry for the externals. I was hoping however to overlay the transparent icon on top of the text instead of beneath. The padding is useful however, but still puts the text on top.

Comment: Yes, I over read the visible overlay need..The problem is if something is `over` the select it wouldn't be clickable/selectable any more (and there is no convenient way to fire a _open select_ event with javascript which works in all browsers. You might want to search for html input (select in your case) alternatives which are probably more easily styleable. Or style a ul - li with hover lists (like in a menu).

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<label>Please select a long menu item</label>
<div class=" new">
  <select name="series" id="series" tabindex="2" class="form-control " onChange="SetSeriesNumber()">
    <option value="" class="select-placeholder" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select Sermon Series</option>
    <option value="252">Brand New Series</option>
    <option value="119">Certain | Secure | Illuminated: Studies in 1 John</option>
    <option value="251" selected="selected">God Theory LIVE</option>  
    <option value="115">One Off Sermons</option>
    <option value="249">This is a cool series</option>
    <option value="250">This is a test series!</option>
    <option value="37">Christmas Hits</option>
    <option value="40">Ephesians: Church, the Manifold Wisdom of God Part 1</option>
    <option value="39">Exodus: The Great Escape Part 1</option>
    <option value="38">Faith Works</option>
    <option value="53">Joseph and The Gospel of Many Colours</option>
    <option value="253">Series Topic</option>
    <option value="125">The Bible - Believing, Feeling, Doing</option>
   <option value="127">The Kingdom of God is Like...</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.new{
  background: url(https://test.sermonmanager.net/assets/images/icons/input-box-fade.png) no-repeat right transparent;
 background-position: 100%;
 background-size:200px;
 background-color:#ddd;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0 0 10px;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 width: 300px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 overflow: hidden; 
 border-radius: 3px;
}
select {
 padding: 5px 38px 5px 8px;
 width: 103%;
 border: none;
 box-shadow: none;
 background-color: transparent;
 background-image: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
}
```

Comment: Um what is this exactly supposed to do? I copy and pasted exactly and all you added was a Javascript function with no code?

Comment: no need of javascript here, you can check without JS

Comment: But still doesn't work? The image still is underneath the content

Comment: I can see it's working perfect. Please review below link for JSFIDDLE. So you can get better idea.
https://jsfiddle.net/oom0aokh/

This is what you need?

Comment: No Mukesh. Without wanting to be a pain. This solution isn't right. I want the  icon to *overlay* the select box. So that the text goes beneath the icon. Do I need to use `z-index` ?